# replicate pouchDB document with couchDB

Tags: javascript, couchdb, pouchdb

I have used pouchDB in one application and now I want to introduce couchDB to sync the document to remote server. Hence i followed this link http://pouchdb.com/getting-started.html i used the below code to replicate the data to couchDB

```
var db2 = new PouchDB('todos');
var remoteCouch = 'http://localhost:5984/_utils/database.html?couchdb_sample';

 db2.changes({
since: 'now',
live: true
}).on('change', showTodos);
sync();
function sync() {
 //alert("sync");
//syncDom.setAttribute('data-sync-state', 'syncing');
//var opts = {live: true};
db2.replicate.to(remoteCouch).on('complete', function () {
console.log("done");
}).on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});

function addTodo(text) {
var todo = {
_id: $("#eid").val()+$("#version").val(),
title: text,
name: $("#nameid").val(),
version: $("#version").val(),
completed: false
};
db2.put(todo, function callback(err, result) {
  if (!err) {
    console.log('Successfully posted a todo!');
  }
  else{
  console.log(err);
  }
 });}
```

here the title has an xml string as value. But i am facing below error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

    at Object.parse (native)
```

for this line db2.replicate.to(remoteCouch). I manually created a new document in couchDb database and entered the same data it gave no error but when i try replicating it shows syntax error. Can anyone please hint me where I have gone wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
http://localhost:5984/_utils/database.html?couchdb_sample
```

Points to a HTML site (copied over from the browsers address bar, right?). Remove the middle part:

```
http://localhost:5984/couchdb_sample
```

Comment: I removed the database.html but now I am getting another error NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed , but I have enabled cors section in local.ini file.

Comment: That is another question you should ask in a separated thread. If my answer has helped you please respect the SO rules and mark it as solved.

Comment: My pleasure! Post the link to your follow-up question in a comment here to notify me.

Answer (score 0):

It look like you have not defined the remote database in the way PouchDb is expecting. You should use the "new PouchDb" call. The second line of your code is:

```
var remoteCouch = 'http://localhost:5984/_utils/database.html?couchdb_sample';
```

but I think it should be like this:

```
var remoteCouch = new PouchDB('http://localhost:5984/couchdb_sample');
```

I am not clear from your code what the name of the remote database is, but it would not normally end in ".html" as Ingo Radatz pointed out, so I have assumed it is *couchdb_sample* above. There is more information about replication on [the PouchDb site](https://pouchdb.com/guides/replication.html).